# How can I define variadic fields on a struct? Go

Tags: types, go

I need a data structure which accepts name / value pairs in addition to custom fields. How can I define a such structure ?

e.g.

```
type mybasket struct {
    Coupons string
    Amount int
    ....... // string or int
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the Go FAQ: Union and variant types are discussed there.

Comment: Also, `map[string]interface{}` is another all-purpose "bag of stuff" type. You'll need a map lookup and a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to unpack the contents. If you can figure out how to avoid doing something dynamic here, that's likely a good thing, because declaring the fields and types ahead of time often catches more mistakes during compilation (easier debugging) and can get you faster-running code.

Comment: This question is very unclear.  What do you mean by "accepts" name/value pairs?  Or "custom" fields?  Does the "string or int" mean you're asking for a data type that represents either a string or an int?  Can you be more concrete about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta that's right. Except Coupons and Amount the structure should "accept" values which are either int or string. Note that the number of fields should be variadic/unlimited.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend defining `setter` and `getter` methods on the type, and store the values in a slice in the struct.

For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type kv struct {
    k, v string
}

type mybasket struct {
    Coupons  string
    Amount   int
    Contents []kv
}

func (t *mybasket) SetContents(c ...kv) {
    t.Contents = c
    return
}

func (t *mybasket) GetContents() []kv {
    return t.Contents
}

func main() {
    T := &mybasket{"couponlist", 100, []kv{}} // New Basket
    kvs := []kv{{"foo", "bar"}, {"baz", "bat"}} // Contents
    T.SetContents(kvs...) // Set Contents
    fmt.Printf("%v", T.GetContents()) // Get Contents
}
```

Prints:

```
[{foo bar} {baz bat}]
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/_PRdj1GZjX)